# Jquery animation quandry

Tags: jquery, animation

I am having a problem where a div slides into view, but has a piece missing from it that only shows up after the sliding action stops.

The div is materializing from 'display:none', and here is the relevant jquery:

```
$('#maincontent').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
})
```

You can view the live page and the source here:

http://joepolitic.com/sites/AlmostFamous.html

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If you remove the h1 and the p tags from inside that div... does the problem persist?

Comment: no, it does not persist, Thanks, Genius!

Comment: I think it has to do with how the browser renders padding/margin. H1 and p tags have default settings for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with how the browser renders margin and padding. H1 and P tags have default values for margin and padding.

The background will show up if you remove the h1 and p tags, or if you style out the margin and padding like this:

```
h1,p{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the section 8.3.1 of the CSS1 specification is relevant: the margin of the  #maincontent div and the margin of the h1 are collapsing while the #maincontent div is positioned relatively in the jQuery-generated ui-effect-wrapper.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Adding 1-pixel padding on the #maincontent div prevents the margins collapsing, and fixes the problem while allowing you to keep margins around the h1.

```
#maincontent {
    padding: 1px;
}
```